# Import function from flask app module without launching app

Tags: python, flask, python-import

I'd like to import functions defined in my `flask` `app` module without launching the app.

My setup is the following:

```
my_app.py
config.py
app
|___ __init__.py
|___ functions.py
|___ routes.py
```

with `__init__.py` containing:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

from app import routes
```

and `my_app.py` containing:

```
from app import app
```

Now when I do:

```
from app.functions import function1
```

In some other script, because of the way `__init__.py` is built, this will launch the app, which I don't want. Is there a workaround?

Note: I know that the easy solution would be to move those functions outside the `app` module and to import them in the `app` module. I am just curious to whether I can do differently.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you put your app creation into a `create_app` function, like so:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    return app
```

Then the app does not get started when the module loads.

This is called **application factory**.

See also the official documentation:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I tried to define the function in my `__init__.py` and to call it in `my_app.py` (is that what you had in mind?) and to replace all calls to `app` instance in sub-modules (e.g. `routes.py`) by `flask.current_app` but I get the following error:

`RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.`

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: For development, you do not have to call `create_app` anywhere. You usually do a `export FLASK_APP=path_to_the_root_of_your_app` (in your case this would be `app`) in the terminal, and then do a `flask run` in the terminal. When you deploy your app to production, you usually use `gunicorn` - but this is another topic. This is all described in the documentation link I gave in the answer.

Comment: Well all I can take out from it for now is that it's not super simple. I'll consider the other solution - putting `functions.py` in a module outside `app`

Comment: In the long term you really should use the application factory - it is not much more complicated. You basically do a `flask run` instead of `python my_app.py`. And only the factory enables easy testing, deployment and so on.

Comment: Actually I do `flask run` and still get the issue ; I may need to create an app context? It is suggested by the error message.

Comment: Depends what is in your `functions` - maybe it is a good idea to add that information to your question above.

Comment: There are notably calls to `app` (or `current_app`) outside the functions (literally in the module) which I suspect should not occur any place else than in `routes.py` (since routes is imported in `__init__.py`). I removed those. But now I get the same error I mentionned with the decorator in `routes.py`. The following line triggers the error:

`@current_app.route('/welcome',methods=['GET'])`

Comment: It would be easier if you put your code in your question. `@current_app.route(...)` is wrong, at least when you import current app from flask. The name after the @ symbol has to be the variable you assigned the instantiated Flask application to - or in case you use blueprints, an instantiated blueprint. I am here to help, but maybe it would be a good idea to learn more about the basics in e.g. https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world - thats a great tutorial.

Comment: The whole code is too big. I can work on a simple example though. I get that `current_app` doesn't work as proxy for decorators, so I'll leave `app` in `routes.py`. I don't need to import anything from `routes.py` anyways. 

Then I still get the same issue with `flask.current_app` in other places. I probably didn't get it right. Looking at the doc more thoroughly, it seems that it's actually working with an app context. The solution is probably that I should refer to the `app` instance only in `routes.py`. Will work on this.

This tutorial is indeed one of the best I have been through.